# Sudden graphic card change? from Nvidia 8600GT to Nvidia 7050/Nvidia nForce 610i

Tags: graphics-card, troubleshooting, nvidia-graphics-card

Yesterday I got a virus and I had the Nvidia 8600 gt, as I have had throughout the whole time I had this computer. So I decided to fully format my pc to get rid of the virus.

When it was finished, It came up with Nvidia 7050/ Nvidia nForce 610i in my systems and all my games have significantly gone down by fps.

Note the driver update that came with the PC that works for Nvidia 8600gt doesnt work anymore, I have tried to download it but it comes with an error message saying that the PC has an incompatible graphics card.

Can anyone explain this sudden change? I know for sure I have bought an Nvidia 8600 gt, and not the current one I have.

Answer (score 6):

the 7050/610i is an integrated video chipset. You probably have your monitor connected to the wrong card. Make sure that it is actually plugged in to the 8600GT and not the motherboard's video header and then install the appropriate driver.